# Take one image as "dimensions template" and use it for resize another images

Tags: imagemagick

I'd like to know syntax for such task: I have one file which is "dimensions template" - it has its own WxH. IM should read this dimensions and use them for resizing of other file ONLY.

As for now, I have such command working:

`magick template.jpg image-to-resize.jpg -resize "x%[fx:int(h/2)]" second-image-resized.jpg`

But calling this command outputs two images - first and second taken as input - resized. How to tell 'fx' that it should read dimensions from first input image?

I use IM v7.1.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.

EDIT: in the meantime I asked the same on IM discussion board on GitHub. I got excellent solution from snibgo: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/7090#discussioncomment-8395013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command starts by reading the template image and the input image. Next it sets a variable using an FX expression to calculate the resize. Then it deletes the template image before resizing and outputting the result.

```
magick template.jpg image.jpg -set option:high %[fx:u.h/2] -delete 0 -resize x%[high] resized.jpg
```

The "u.h" in the expression specifies that the height of the first image, the template, is used for the calculation. The command simply deletes that template before the resize operation.